# Dealing with milliseconds when casting String to timestamp in SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, casting, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have a column in a SparkDataFrame containing timestamps in the following way:

```
    Start_1
    <chr>
    2016/01/01 10:51:15.304 
    2016/01/01 10:51:15.352
```

I let Spark infer the schema when reading the file, which yields chr as data type.  I know that it would work without the millseconds, yielding the proper data type and column. However I need the milliseconds as well and wanted therefore to change the datatype to timestamp within the existing Spark Data Frame.

Here are the ways I have tested:

as POSIXct would work in base R.

```
    dataloan_time$start_ts <- as.POSIXct(dataloan$Start_1, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%OS")
```

- doesn't work (doesn't know to change the class).

A solution mentioned here and on other sites mentions casting:

```
    dataloan_time <- withColumn(dataloan_time, "complete_ts", cast(dataloan$Complete_1, "timestamp"))
```

For me, it casts the data type correctly but the new column doesn't contain any data.

Here's the result for head(col)

```
    start_ts
    <lgl>
    NA  
    NA
```

Collecting the data frame and changing it would be the last option I found, but I'd like to avoid that and do it within the Spark Data frame.
What other solutions are there? Ideally, it would be like the first try (as POSIXct).

Comment: do you need to keep it as a "timestamp"? or would a float/double representation be acceptable

Answer (score 1):

I jumped on this because I thought it might be something simple, I don't think its that simple anymore :)
Environment=Spark:1.5.2

```
#setup; probably a better way to set this up, oh well, R isn't my first language
d <- c("2016/01/01 10:51:15.304","2016/01/01 10:51:15.352")
df1 <- data.frame(d)
df = createDataFrame(sqlContext, df1)
```

start of my confusion:

```
> as.numeric(as.POSIXct(d))
[1] 1451663475 1451663475
```

why does it say the same number? they are different!!

```
> print(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(d[1])),digits=20)
[1] 1451663475.3039999008
> print(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(d[2])),digits=20)
[1] 1451663475.3519999981
```

Okay, so now I know they are represented the same way, just being printed not to my liking
([How to parse milliseconds in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150138/how-to-parse-milliseconds-in-r) lead me down the printing path)

from [Writing R data frames returned from SparkR:::map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33961103/writing-r-data-frames-returned-from-sparkrmap)
I found a way to make UDF

```
rows <- SparkR:::flatMap(df, function(x) {
  data <- as.list(x)
  datanew <- append(data,as.POSIXct(data[[1]]))
  args <- list(FUN = list, SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  do.call(mapply, append(args, datanew))
})
sdf <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, rows,c("origdt","rownum","newdt"))
```

if we now do normal prints of the dataframe we aren't gonna like what we see

```
head(sdf)
                   origdt rownum      newdt
1 2016/01/01 10:51:15.304      1 1451663475
2 2016/01/01 10:51:15.352      2 1451663475

#register it so we can run sql
registerTempTable(sdf,"sdf")
```

However if we order by "newdt" we can see that they are being converted correctly

```
head(sql(sqlContext,"select * from sdf order by newdt"))
                   origdt rownum      newdt
1 2016/01/01 10:51:15.304      1 1451663475
2 2016/01/01 10:51:15.352      2 1451663475

head(sql(sqlContext,"select * from sdf order by newdt desc"))

                   origdt rownum      newdt
1 2016/01/01 10:51:15.352      2 1451663475
2 2016/01/01 10:51:15.304      1 1451663475
```

We can also look at the underlying rdd data to confirm that the conversions happened as we expected:

```
print(take(rows,1)[[1]][[3]],digits=20)
[1] 1451663475.3039999008
```

Note:
I've kept them as doubles the whole time because I assume the end-goal is to do datediff kinda things anyway, if you NEED the timestamp-timestamp representation I would think that you could alter the UDF to have it be stored as such

Comment: First of all, thanks for taking the time for this great solution! Unfortunately, I use Spark 2.1.0 and the problem is that, after executing the command to create "rows", I use createDataFrame as you did (with sqlContext). Howeever, the resulting data frame only has the two first columns? newDT doesn't show up ...

Comment: well that's no fun :( I don't have a readily available spark 2.1.0 Env nor is R my first language choice, so that makes proceeding difficult, Sorry :(